# JMS selector strange behaviour

Tags: java, queue, jms, selector

In JMS consider the following pseudo-code:

Sender:

```
    QueueSender qs = session.createSender(queue);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 10)
    {   
        TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
        msg.setText(""+i);

         msg.setIntProperty("value", i);

        qs.send(msg);
        i++;
    }
```

Receiver:

```
String sel = "value >2";
QueueReceiver qr = session.createReceiver(q,sel);

while(true)
{
 TextMessage tm = (TextMessage) qr.receive();
 System.out.println(tm.getText);
}
```

I would have expected the consumer not to consume/print anything becauses the messages he is interested at are blocked by the messages 0,1,2 that are not being pulled by any consumer.

What I see instead is the consumer printing out all the messages selected by its selector...

Is that the correct behaviour of JMS ?
Is that documented somewhere ?

thanks.

Comment: What is `qs`? Can you show how it has been initialized?

Comment: Try changing `value >2` to `value>2` just to be sure that it's not a parsing error.

Comment: Still the Same Output

Comment: At this point, I have to say that the output is as expected. A selector will not block other messages from being read. It will just cause the listener to ignore those messages and continue with the rest. Can you add the output printed by your reciever as part of your question? See my answer and let me know if you have any further doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would have expected the consumer not to consume/print anything
>   becauses the messages he is interested at are blocked by the messages
>   0,1,2 that are not being pulled by any consumer

This assumption is incorrect. When you use a selector in `JMS`, the messages that do not satisfy the selector expression will not be delivered to the `QueueReceiver`. The `QueueReciever` will continue to read all those messages that satisfy the selector expression.

I believe that your output contains the numbers from 3 - 10. . This is the expected behavior. See the documentation for the [createReceiver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jms/javadoc-102a/javax/jms/QueueSession.html#createReceiver(javax.jms.Queue,%20java.lang.String)) method.

Comment: yes the output is just that,so JMS Queues are not properly FIFO queues ?

Comment: @GionJh JMS **never** was or meant to be FIFO, it does **not** guarantee sequence at all

Comment: I guess that the term bucket or set instead of queue would have been more appropriate then...Thanks ;)

Comment: @GionJh I can't generalize this since different providers may implement queues differently. That being said, If I have answered your immediate question, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer.